# How to get a response of file printing job to user from printer using CUPS in linux

Tags: linux, perl, printing, cups

I am  trying to print a file  in remote server through CUPS command , User needs to know the status of  job status. How to get a response from that. Here is my code :

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 my $response = system("lpr -P laserJet123   -o raw -T test_womargin abc.txt");
 print $response;
```

Comment: Please check `system()` docs; http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: @Сухой27,   perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html  helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

$? returns the response status of system command.

```
system("lpr -P laserJet123   -o raw -T test_womargin abc.txt");
if ($? == -1) {
print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
printf "Job failed with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
($? & 127), ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
 printf "Job exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```